# Nuitka Dependancy Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a simple standalone python application using Nuitka. I was able to do this using just the standard library.

I'm now looking to bring in some extra dependancies but I am now receiving errors from Nuitka I'm unable to interpret.

I've tried to import numpy into the project which looks like:

Structure:

- npg

  - __init__.py
  - __main__.py
- Pipfile
- Pipfile.lock

Here's the `__main__.py`

```
import numpy as np


def main():
    print('hello Nuitka')
    print('hello numpy', np.__version__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I then run `python -m nuitka npg/__main__.py --standalone` and get the error:

```
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/pytesttester.py:125: Cannot find 'pytest' in package 'numpy.testing._private' as absolute import (tried pytest).
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py:20: Cannot find 'setuptools.extern.six.moves' in package 'setuptools.command' as absolute import (tried setuptools.extern.six.moves).
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py:20: Cannot find 'setuptools.extern.six' in package 'setuptools.command' as absolute import (tried setuptools.extern.six).
Nuitka:WARNING:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/glob.py:13: Cannot find 'setuptools.extern.six' in package 'setuptools' as absolute import (tried setuptools.extern.six).
Nuitka:WARNING:Problem at '<SourceCodeReference to /usr/src/app/npg/__main__.py:4>' with FunctionDef(name='main', args=arguments(args=[], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]), body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='hello Nuitka')], keywords=[])), Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='hello numpy'), Attribute(value=Name(id='np', ctx=Load()), attr='__version__', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], decorator_list=[], returns=None).
Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:566:
->             from __main__ import __requires__

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:565:
->         try:

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:559:
->     @classmethod

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:559:
->     @classmethod

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:543:
-> class WorkingSet:

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:543:
-> class WorkingSet:

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:543:
-> class WorkingSet:

Problem with statement at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:543:
-> class WorkingSet:

Nuitka:INFO:Interrupted while working on '<Node 'COMPILED_PYTHON_PACKAGE' with {'filename': '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py', 'package': None, 'name': 'pkg_resources'}>'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/__main__.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/__main__.py", line 212, in main
    MainControl.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/MainControl.py", line 800, in main
    filename = filename
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/MainControl.py", line 152, in createNodeTree
    Optimization.optimize(main_module.getOutputFilename())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/Optimization.py", line 533, in optimize
    makeOptimizationPass(initial_pass = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/Optimization.py", line 446, in makeOptimizationPass
    changed = optimizeModule(current_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/Optimization.py", line 173, in optimizeModule
    changed = optimizeCompiledPythonModule(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/Optimization.py", line 97, in optimizeCompiledPythonModule
    module.computeModule()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ModuleNodes.py", line 461, in computeModule
    trace_collection = self.trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 165, in computeStatementsSequence
    trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FrameNodes.py", line 195, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/TryNodes.py", line 129, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 169, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/AssignNodes.py", line 297, in computeStatement
    trace_collection.onExpression(self.getAssignSource())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/OutlineNodes.py", line 247, in computeExpressionRaw
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 169, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/TryNodes.py", line 129, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 169, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/TryNodes.py", line 129, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 165, in computeStatementsSequence
    trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FrameNodes.py", line 195, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/LocalsDictNodes.py", line 406, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/NodeBases.py", line 933, in computeStatementSubExpressions
    expression = expression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ExpressionBases.py", line 976, in computeExpressionRaw
    expression = trace_collection.onExpression(sub_expression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ExpressionBases.py", line 976, in computeExpressionRaw
    expression = trace_collection.onExpression(sub_expression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ExpressionBases.py", line 976, in computeExpressionRaw
    expression = trace_collection.onExpression(sub_expression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FunctionNodes.py", line 901, in computeExpressionRaw
    function_body.computeFunctionRaw(trace_collection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FunctionNodes.py", line 408, in computeFunctionRaw
    self.computeFunction(trace_collection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FunctionNodes.py", line 422, in computeFunction
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 169, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/TryNodes.py", line 129, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 165, in computeStatementsSequence
    trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FrameNodes.py", line 195, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/TryNodes.py", line 129, in computeStatement
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/StatementNodes.py", line 169, in computeStatementsSequence
    statement = statement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 575, in onStatement
    statement.computeStatement(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/AssignNodes.py", line 297, in computeStatement
    trace_collection.onExpression(self.getAssignSource())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ExpressionBases.py", line 1054, in computeExpressionRaw
    expression = sub_expression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/optimizations/TraceCollections.py", line 550, in onExpression
    trace_collection = self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ExpressionBases.py", line 998, in computeExpressionRaw
    trace_collection = trace_collection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ImportNodes.py", line 400, in computeExpression
    module_name      = imported_module_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ImportNodes.py", line 290, in _attemptRecursion
    module_package   = module_package
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/ImportNodes.py", line 222, in _consider
    reason          = reason
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/importing/Recursion.py", line 169, in recurseTo
    reason          = reason
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/importing/Recursion.py", line 92, in _recurseTo
    is_main     = False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/Building.py", line 1055, in createModuleTree
    is_main     = is_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/Building.py", line 760, in buildParseTree
    source_ref = source_ref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/TreeHelpers.py", line 384, in buildStatementsNode
    statements = buildNodeList(provider, nodes, source_ref, allow_none = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/TreeHelpers.py", line 338, in buildNodeList
    entry = buildNode(provider, node, node_source_ref, allow_none)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/TreeHelpers.py", line 295, in buildNode
    source_ref = source_ref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/ReformulationFunctionStatements.py", line 153, in buildFunctionNode
    source_ref    = source_ref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/tree/ReformulationFunctionStatements.py", line 799, in buildFunctionWithParsing
    source_ref = source_ref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FunctionNodes.py", line 452, in __init__
    source_ref  = source_ref
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/FunctionNodes.py", line 386, in __init__
    setLocalsDictType(self.locals_dict_name, "python3_function")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuitka/nodes/LocalsScopes.py", line 30, in setLocalsDictType
    assert locals_dict_name not in locals_dict_handles, locals_dict_name
AssertionError: locals___main__$$$function_1_main
```

I'm use how to interpret that error. Looks like it's having problems with the syntax of the Python's standard libraries import machinery.

Comment: You will probably be better off asking on the nuitka website.